# MATLAB: find means of other rows in a matrix without loop

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, vectorization, mean

I'm optimizing my codes. Now I have an MxN matrix, and I want to generate a mean MxN matrix which is the mean of other rows

for example: if i have matrix A:

1 2 3

3 4 5

2 3 2

In the new matrix B, I want each one is the mean of other rows.

mean(row2,row3)

mean(row1,row3)

mean(row1,row2)

I've think of many ways, but can't avoid a loop

```
    for row=1:3
        temp = A;
        temp(row,:) = [];
        B(row,:) = mean(temp);
    end
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
B = (bsxfun(@minus,sum(A,1),A))./(size(A,1)-1)
```

The trick is to subtract the current row from the sum all rows with `bsxfun` in a vectorized manner, thus giving us the sum of all rows except the current one. Finally, get the average values by dividing them by the number of rows minus `1`.

Comment: smart way! it may be okay to get rid of the "." before "/" too

Comment: @FF0605 Not at all! `./` means elementwise division, what is we need, not the matrix division of `/`.

Comment: what I meant was (size(A,1)-1) is a single number, so it doesn't really matter if it's elementwise :P  thanks for the smart solution!

Comment: Dear Divakar, I just posted another question to avoid loop in a matrix, could you please have a look?